# how can I statistic my key press frequency and count

Tags: linux, keyboard, keypress, frequency-analysis

I am try to remap my keyboard to type better.

But I need to know the frequency of each key include symbol, It will be great if include tab shift ctrl. I need all the keypress acounting not only frequency of letters appears in english words.

I am using ibus-pinyin as my input method. and archlinux, awesome wm, without kde and gnome installed. any programes could help me?

BTW:
what's wrong with dvorak.
http://colemak.com/FAQ#What.27s_wrong_with_the_Dvorak_layout.3F

but colemak is not fit for me too, cause I want more synmbols.

but I have to keep some numbers, 1-5 to select chinese word from ibus, you know pinyin letters frequency is not same as english letters.

Comment: Perhaps read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512/best-keyboard-for-custom-dvorak-based-programming-layout

Comment: not so easy, actually, colemak has explain what's wrong with dvorak.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ xwininfo
```

Now hit your terminal window with the mouse to obtain the window's id from the line like that:

`xwininfo: Window id: 0x1e0000f "green"`

Ask `xev` utility to track `X` events of your window, logging its output.

`$ xev -id 0x1e0000f > log &`

Type in some text and get your statistics from the log, filtering the keyreleases:

```
$ grep keysym log| sed -e "s/).*//" -e "s/.* //"| sort | uniq -c
      1 b
      2 c
      2 Control_L
      2 d
      1 e
      3 f
      3 g
      2 j
      1 k
      2 l
      1 n
      1 q
      1 r
      8 Return
      2 s
      1 t
      1 u
      1 v
      1 w
      1 y
      1 z
```

Comment: It's a pitty, exactly what i was searching for, but the last Command give emtd response, even if the logfile contains data.
Log looks like this: http://paste.kde.org/ps2rlqoyd